# Onclick on a programmatically generated element

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have programmatically generated a lot of textblocks. I would like to bind onclick function to them... it's easy if I write the textblock to my xaml code, but how can I do it if the textblocks are programmatically generated?

What I have this far:

```
TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
tb1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(MyTextBlock_KeyDown);
...
private void MyTextBlock_KeyDown(object sender, GestureEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide your XAML so that an accurate C# version can be provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
    block.Text = "Tap me";
    block.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(block_Tap);

    TitlePanel.Children.Add(block);
}

void block_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

This works just fine...

Comment: I get the error: No overload for 'MyTextBlock_KeyDown' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler'

Comment: Did you create the event handler? You should adapt the sample code I posted to make it work with your specific code.

Comment: What the problem that you have?

Comment: No overload for 'MyTextBlock_KeyDown' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler' is the error I get...

Comment: I edited the answer, you have the event arguments defined incorrectly. It's not GestureEventArgs....

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors now, it lets me compile it, but the click does not work... how can I use tap instead, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: No problem. But you should read a bit more about C# in general... ;)